# Proof of Eckart-Young Theorem (Mathematics for Machine Learning, Deisenroth)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, data-analysis, principal-component-analysis

I am trying to understand a proof of the Eckart-Young Theorem (source in title). Let me add the definition and proof they provided, afterward I'll say what I do not understand.
[image: Theorem]
Proof:
[image: Proof (Part)]

Some points I do not understand:

- Why does 4.98 holds?
- Couldn't the same/similar argument of "then there exists an at least $(n − k)$-dimensional null space of $\mathbf{B}$" also be made for $\hat{\mathbf{A}}(k)$ "there exists an exactly $(n − k)$-dimensional null space", since the rank is $k$? -> maybe I get that this proves that there can not be a matrix of smaller rank that better approximates it, but I do not understand how it proves that this $\hat{\mathbf{A}}(k)$ is the best matrix of rank $k$ that approximates it (probably because I do not understand why 4.98 holds?)

Comment: 4.98 holds because $Bx = 0$. The point of the proof is to assume that there is a better rank $k$ approximation of $A$, namely $B$, and to arrive at a contradiction, therefore proving that $\hat{A}$ is the best. I believe it is also assumed that the $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $A$ and that they are ordered as $\sigma_1 \geq ... \geq \sigma_r, r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. but doesn't $\mathbf{Bx}= \mathbf{0}$ only hold for $\mathbf{x} \in Z$? So why can we then basically generalize it? And I do get the point of the proof and the goal, but the steps to the result are not really clear to me.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the premise. What do you mean by "generalize it"? We're not generalizing anything. $(A-B)x = Ax$ holds for this particular $x$. Perhaps you're getting confused by 4.99?

Comment: Please avoid using images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).